# Parsing from an output text file and structuring it a specific way in a text file

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could assist me in making code that could parse values and make a txt file. I wrote two codes where the first one is the one that creates output files. And the second code extracts the values and puts it in a text file. The first code will create unique output files with the weight and length in it for example weight_0.1_length_.txt where each file will have the example below inside. The weight will go in increments of 0.1 to 1 and the length 0,4,8,16,25,30. And after 1 has reached for a specific length, the weight will start over and go to the next length.

```
  weight of box 0.1
  length of box 2
  ratio 20.0
```

each file will have a value 'ratio' that corresponds to the values of weight and length.

My problem is, my second code does not put the values into a text file the way I would like to. For example it will write a file like

```
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;0.0;0.0
  0.1;2.0;20.0
  0.1;2.0;20.0
  0.1;2.0;20.0
  0.1;2.0;20.0
```

this is not the way I would like my extracted text file to be. and for some reason my first column is only the value 0.1, but it should go from 0.1 to 1. I am trying to make one where I would get weight in the first column and the next 6 columns be the 'ratio' values corresponding with the length and weight. For example

```
  weight; length at 0, length at 4
  0.1;ratio,ratio
  0.2;ratio;ratio
  0.3;ratio;ratio
  0.4;ratio;ratio
  0.5;ratio;ratio
  0.6;ratio;ratio
  0.7;ratio;ratio
  0.8;ratio;ratio
  0.9;ratio;ratio
  1.0;ratio;ratio
```

where the ratio is the value the corresponds with a specific length and wight

```
  --------'This is the first code that creates output files'-------

  lengths = [0,2,4,8,16,25,30]

  for l in lengths:
      Weight = 0.1
      for i in range (10):
          input = 'weight_' +str(Weight)+ '_length_' +str(l)+ '_' 
          file = open(input + '.txt','w')

          C = l/Weight

          file.write('weight of box ' +str(Weight)+ '\n')
          file.write('length of box ' +str(l)+ '\n')
          file.write('ratio ' +str(C)+ '\n')
          file.close()

          Weight = round(Weight + 0.1, 1)
      lengths = 1

  ------'This is the second code that parses and that '------
  ------'that doesn't work correctly'-------

  lengths = [0,2,4,8,16,25,30]

  for l in lengths:
      weight = 0.1
      for j in range(10):
          file = open('weight_' +str(weight) + '_length_' +str(l)+ '_.txt','r')
          file_lines = file.readlines()
          for line in file_lines:
              if 'weight of box' in line:
                  Weight_loc = line.index('weight of box')
                  W = float(line[Weight_loc + 14:])
              if 'length of box' in line:
                  length_loc = line.index('length of box')
                  L = float(line[length_loc + 14:])
              if 'ratio' in line:
                  ratio_loc = line.index('ratio')
                  R = float(line[ratio_loc + 6:])

          output = open('extracted.txt', 'a')
          output.writelines(str(W)+ ';')
          output.writelines(str(L)+ ';')
          output.writelines(str(R)+ '\n')
          output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be updating the value of `weight` in the second part of the code. So you are just opening the same file 10 times and reading from it, then doing the same thing with the next file, etc. Hence add this to the end of the second code:

```
weight = round(weight + 0.1, 1)
```

I think that will do it, though the code is not particularly easy to read. This would be much simpler if you wrote your files in csv format, incidentally. Then you would write one line across the top containing column names, and then the data underneath:

```
weight_of_box,length_of_box,ratio
0.1,2,20.0
```

That makes processing each file very simple especially if you learn numpy & pandas.